# Windows Server 2012 NAT Routing won't route clients from subnet (multiple external ips)

Tags: routing, windows-server-2012, nat

I obviously have some knowledge gaps in routing maybe you can help me:

My ISP has given me 8 external IPs but I have to route them myself. The first IP is issued via DHCP and the other 7 are fixed.

This is what my network looks like right now (all Servers are Windows Server 2012):

[image: The Network]

What I'm trying to do is route one of the external IPs to "Server 1" so all outgoing traffic will have that IP and also that I can connect to its VPN Server.

This is working like charm. The Server got the IP and can connect just fine but no client in any of the subnets (VLANs) can connect.
They all can ping the Server 1, even on the 10.12.0.2 IP but they can't connect to the internet, nor can they ping the firewall (10.12.0.1).

In every subnet, Server 1 is the gateway (LAN routing). DNS Requests are forwarded successfully, but any other package are lost.

**So whats working:**

```
Server 1 -> Firewall -> Internet
```

**What's not working:**

```
Client -> Server 1 -> [x] Firewall -> [x] Internet
```

In case I made some mistakes in the config: Here are some screenshots from the Server (It's german, sorry but everything should be where it is in the english version)

And yes I know it's not the Firewall or AV because I tried disabling everything.

[image: Server is configured to act as NAT on the WAN interface]

Server is configured to act as NAT on the WAN interface

[image: Server has the addresspool configured]

Server has the addresspool configured

[image: I have bound the 211 IP to the Server 1]

I have bound the 211 IP to the Server 1

I'd appreciate any pointers

Comment: What's the business need behind using the server like a very expensive and cumbersome multi-port NAT router?

Comment: It was actually the cheapest solution since we don't have to pay for individual Windows licenses (MS-ACH agreement) and the server is a VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Hopefully it will help someone else too.

I forgot to add RIP to all Server's routing protocols. Without RIP the packages seem to be unable to take the addet hop from Server to the Firewall to the net.

After adding RIP everything worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be complicating things by trying to route traffic through the server. You can configure a NAT rule on the firewall to send outbound traffic over a specific public IP.

Comment: Well I displayed my network more simple than it is. I actually have multiple Servers in the 10.12.0.x space and each one should have its own IP. I could of course route all traffic via one IP but that's not what I want actually